# problems with database connection with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have set the correct DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD to the .env file, and in the command line "php artisan migrate" works for me!!

However, when I dd(User::all()) ,it shows

Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users`)

I trying echo env('DB_USERNAME'); //the output is 'homestead'

Any idea ?

Comment: What environment are you using, eg xamp, vagrant, docker etc?

Comment: @morph  Mac built in php environment

Comment: are you able to try this from tinker `php artisan tinker` then do `App\User::all()`

Comment: Are you running it with `php artisan serve`? If so restart server.

Comment: you could try to clear the cache after the changed credentials in the .env file `php artisan cache:clear`, then try it. @kuzicala

Comment: @TimvanUum Solve my problem thanks all